# How should I texture paint on my model after I already UV Mapped and created a texture material with a texture atlas?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

I used the texture atlas technique to UV map and create the textures for my model. However, now I want to just texture paint pixel like eyes and nose onto the models face(stylistic choice).

Could anyone help explain how I do that from here? I was able to do it in tests before I UV Mapped the entire model and finished the texture atlas technique, but now I don't know how I can add a texture paint on the face post making her textures.

Here's my model below

[image: my model]

Below is what I'm looking to do to create my models eyes and nose.

[image: texture paint pixel face]

When I try texture painting, the smaller brushes are huge and dont draw on correctly. Is this because I scaled down her face in the UV editor mesh?
[image]

thanks so much for any help possible. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: if some parts need to be painted on for some details, you should make sure that the area in the picture is big enough for these details, while all the square that are simply used to project color can be pretty small